# Как в MSTest реализуются модульные тесты для private классов, методов, свойств и т.д.?

Tags: c#, .net, юнит-тесты, test-driven-development, mstest

Понимаю, что, как вариант, можно в самом тестируемом классе создать вложенный класс, который получит доступ ко всем `private` членам внешнего. И даже можно это все оградить конструкцией `#if DEBUGER ... #endif`, но не хотелось бы смешивать тестируемый и тестирующий код. Тесты очень хотелось бы выносить в отдельный проект, как и сделано по умолчанию. В то же время не хотелось бы каждый раз к скрытым полям обращаться через `Reflection`-вызовы, пусть даже вынесенные в классы, методы.

Как это было задумано делать в Microsoft? Есть ли какие-то рекомендации и прочие наработки применительно к MSTest?

Comment: приватные свойства и методы являются вспомогательными для публичных, поэтому при тесте публичных вы неявно тестируете и приватные. К тому же, раз вы упомянули TDD, то по сути важна корректная работа публичного интерфейса, а как вы там внутри ее реализовали, ни кого кроме вас волновать не должно. А вот для тестирования protected методов, которые хоть и не являются публичным интерфейсом, но могут иметь похожие требования, т.к. от них зависит корректная работа производных классов, тестировать можно с помощью специального производного класса.

Comment: Отчасти так, но все же иногда приватная логика может быть настолько сложной, что через публичные ее толком протестировать невозможно. Есть некоторые тонкие места, которые знает только программист, который писал код и именно их он может захотеть проверить. Это как опция к основным тестам публичного интерфейса. Вероятно все же Reflection хорошая идея, но не хотелось бы изобретать колесо с нуля.

Comment: Если все так сложно, то стоит задуматься о возможной ошибке проектирования. На крайний случай, можно особо сложную логику вынести в отдельный класс-хелпер и тестировать его

Comment: Чтобы не отходить от темы предлагаю не обсуждать вопрос "зачем", а обсудить вопрос "как". Если вдруг понадобится протестировать private, то как это сделать, не вмешиваясь в проект.

Comment: А на вопрос "как" вы уже сами ответили - reflection, другого способа "легально" получить доступ к приватным членам нет.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[PrivateObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.privateobject.aspx)

Подходит только для MSTest
Сам с этим не работал, но если кому пригодится:

```
public class Account
{
    public decimal InterestRate { get; private set; }        
    private decimal _balance;
    private int _accountId;

    public Account(int accountId)
    {
        _accountId = accountId;
    }

    public decimal GetBalanceWithInterest()
    {
        return _balance + GetInterest();
    }

    //закрытый метод
    private decimal GetInterest()
    {
        return _balance*InterestRate;
    }
}

[TestMethod]
public void GetInterest_ReturnsExpectedInterest()
    {
        decimal balance = 1000;
        decimal interestRate = (decimal) 0.05;
        decimal expectedInterest = 50;

        var acc = new Account(1000);
        var privateObject = new PrivateObject(acc);

        privateObject.SetField("_balance", balance);
        privateObject.SetProperty("InterestRate", interestRate);

        var interest = privateObject.Invoke("GetInterest");

        Assert.AreEqual(interest, expectedInterest);
   }
```