# Как тестировать private и protected методы?

Tags: c#, test-driven-development, moq

У меня есть класс:

```
public abstract class SomeClass {
    private readonly ISomeInterface _interface;

    protected SomeClass(ISomeInterface interface) {
        this._interface = interface;
    }

    protected virtual void SomeMethod(string someProp) {
        if (_interface == null) throw new ArgumentNullException();
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(someProp)) throw new ArgumentNullException();
    }
}
```

Пытаюсь написать тест, который проверяет будут ли вылетать Exception при разных условиях (на каждый exception свой метод теста). Как вызывать методы я, вроде, понял:

```
[TestMethod]
public void SomeClass_WhenISomeInterfaceIsNull_ShouldThrowArgumentNullException
{
   var someClassMock = new Mock<SomeClass>(null);
   var result = site.Protected().Setup<string>("SomeMethod", "1111");
}
```

Метод, вроде, вызван, но как проверить было ли в нем выброшено исключение?

PS:Ответ предложенный sp7, здесь не походит.
Мой ISomeInterface работает с сетью. Возвращаемый им результат, для данного приложения не походит, например, он возвращает json строку, а конечному классу(наследнику SomeClass) нежен он в виде класса. Реализовывать преобразование из Json в class в ISomeInterface нет смысла, так как:

1. Может потянуться за собой не нужные зависимости(например, Newtonsoft.Json)
2. Будет использоваться в других приложениях, где может быть уже не Json.

Использовать дополнительный класс, в который будет инжектиться ISomeInterface, который в свою очередь будет инжектиться в наследников SomeClass, тоже плохой вариант так как:

1. В методе SomeMethod класса SomeClass выполняются действия зависящие 
   от настроек наследников. Например, количество запросов, которое
   должно быть совершено если не поступил ответ или другим причинам.
2. Выносить настройки SomeClass в ISomeInterface не правильно, так как это 
   приведет к множеству проинициализированных классов реализующих 
   ISomeInterface (что является недопустимым), либо к добавлению сохранения 
   настроек в реализации ISomeInterface (что тоже является недопустимым, так 
   как это не его задача).

Comment: Что это такое у вас тут написано `protected abstract SomeMethod(string someProp) {.....}`?

Comment: Это метод. Ошибся забыл void написать. Исправил

Comment: Вы все-равно не правильно исправили. Уберите `abstract ` в `protected abstract void SomeMethod(string someProp) {.....}`

Comment: Да там должен был быть virtual написал, а не abstract

Comment: Этот ответ я прочитал и он не подходит, потому что в абстрактном классе выполняется часть работ, которая не должна выполняться в реализации ISomeInterface и так же я бы не хотел, чтобы она дублировалась в наследниках.

Comment: Дак а суть то это как меняет. Вопрос стоит относительно тестирования `protected` методов, иерархия классов здесь уже второстепенна или я не понимаю что-то?

Comment: Если вам нужно тестировать `protected` или `private` методы - это говорит о том, что надо менять структуру классов.

Comment: И это нас возвращает к обсуждению [ссылка] (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/321346/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-private-%d0%b8-protected-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%8b). Из которого следует, что использовать абстрактные классы, в которых есть методы и свойства, которые должны быть доступны только наследникам (protected и/или private(не для наследников)) плохо так как для их тестирования нет инструментов

Comment: Ещё по теме: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/208710/10105

Comment: Прочитал ответ по ссылке. С ответом я согласен когда речь заходит о private методах. Но здесь идет речь о protected, которые требуют тестирования.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть рассматривать тот код, который представлен в примере, то для тестов вы просто можете создать еще один класс для тестирования, который будет наследовать SomeClass и открывать нужные вам protected члены класса. Не вижу криминала в подобном подходе.

```
public SomeClassNew : SomeClass {

  public SomeClassNew(ISomeInterface interface) : base(interface)

  public void SomeMethodTest(string someProp) {
    base.SomeMethod(someProp);
  }

}
```

Но лучше сделать конструктор для класса открытым.

Для вызова private методов класса вы можете использовать рефлексию:

```
SomeClass someClass = new SomeClass(someInterface);
MethodInfo methodInfo = typeof(SomeClass).GetMethod("SomeMethod", 
    BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
methodInfo.Invoke(someClass, new object[] { someProp });
```

"Правильность" данного подхода каждый для себя определяет сам, я не вижу в этом ничего дурного. По крайней мере для тестирования.

Comment: А не поясните почему конструктор лучше сделать открытым?
С protected тоже подумал об этом, но решил задать вопрос, так не нашел в инете похожего. А что касается pivate это получается уже нарушение принципов инкапсуляции?

Comment: По поводу private модификатора и инкапсуляции. Тут можно рассматривать вопрос с нескольких точек зрения, разработчика который пользуется кодом и который его разрабатывает/сопровождает. В первом случае ничего не нарушается. Во втором случае иногда приходится прибегать к такому, т.к. надо оттестировать надо именно логику закрытого метода.

Comment: По поводу конструкторов. Лично я вижу всего две причины закрывать его или объявлять его protected. В первом случае, если нужно на этапе получения нового экземпляра произвести какие то действия с уже созданным экземпляром, но еще до присвоения переменной. В таком случае делаем открытый статический конструктор или применяем фабричный метод. Второй случай применим, если мы хотим передать право на создание новых экземпляров класса исключительно потомкам. Иначе говоря принудительно заставить наследовать наш класс. В данном случае можно так же использовать абстрактные классы.

Comment: Этот подход мне кажется неправильным. Задайте себе вопрос: **что** должен тестировать тест? Правильный ответ: соответствие поведения класса спецификации. А какое отношение имеют приватные методы к спецификации? Никакого, это деталь имплементации.

Comment: @VladD, к privat методам это ещё можно отнести(хотя а как точно знать что они работают не протестировав их?). Но это не относиться к protected методам, которые используются только в наследниках, для которых(грубо говоря) они являются public методами, которые уже надо тестировать. В этом и вопрос.

Comment: @Vyacheslav: Вы путаете тесты и отладку. Тесты существуют чтобы проверять соответствие реального поведения класса спецификации. Отладка существует, чтобы проверять выполнение внутренних инвариантов. И нет, protected-методы ни в каком смысле не являются public-методами, на них нет спецификации.

Comment: имел ввиду как public для наследников(хоть и грубо но это так), а не для всех. Про тестирование protected методов есть ответ [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/553253/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2-mstest-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-private-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2-%D0%B8?rq=1) . Первый комментарий.